# Flex 4.5 videodisplay component

Tags: adobe, flex4.5

I am using a spark videodisplay component. The currentTime property is a readonly property.

In previous version flex 3 videodisplay has a equvalent property playheadTime which can be set.

Is there anyway we could set currentTime property. So when moving a slider control the videodisplay componet plays based on the slider value which is bound to the video playheadtime.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself for adobe live docs component reference page videoDisplay.seek(timeValue);